# How do I get an ngram from HiveQL into PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, hiveql, treasure-data

I'm running this query on treasure-data.com (HiveQL):

```
  SELECT
    ngrams (
      sentences (
        LOWER( v[ 'text' ] )
      )
      ,1
      ,100
    )
  FROM
    item
  WHERE
    TD_TIME_RANGE (
      TIME
      ,"2013-08-06"
      ,TD_TIME_ADD (
        "2013-08-06"
        ,"1d"
      )
    )
```

When it comes time to dump the results into PostgreSQL, I get this error:

```
started at 2013-08-06T17:42:52Z
Hive history file=/mnt/hive/tmp/2851/hive_job_log__1663452325.txt
finished at 2013-08-06T17:43:27Z
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid schema: unexpected '>' but got: <ngram:array<string>,estfrequency:double>>
    at com.treasure_data.type.spec.TypeSpecs.scanString(TypeSpecs.java:98)
    at com.treasure_data.type.spec.TypeSpecs.fromString(TypeSpecs.java:72)
    at com.treasure_data.type.spec.TypeSpecs.fromString(TypeSpecs.java:64)
    at com.treasure_data.type.spec.TypeSpecs.fromString(TypeSpecs.java:57)
    at com.treasure_data.hadoop.worker.result.ResultWorker.<init>(ResultWorker.java:59)
    at com.treasure_data.hadoop.worker.result.ResultWorker.main(ResultWorker.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
```

I'm guessing I need to modify my select statement in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

explode!

```
SELECT explode(ngrams(sentences(lower(val)), 2, 10)) AS x FROM kafka;
```

([source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatisticsAndDataMining))